# django-polymorphic inline admin with many to many relation

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.8

Is it possible for a model with many to many relation to a polymorphic model to display stacked inline forms (depending on the type of the child model) ?

Using the [example from the `django-polymorphic`](http://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#manytomanyfield-foreignkey-onetoonefield) docs i'm trying to make the list of `ModelA` models to display as `admin.StackedInline` in the `RelatingModel` admin page, each with it's specific form.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define your inline class base on your related model

```
class MyMode1lInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel1
    extra = 1
```

Now you need to connect your inline to the PolymorphicChildModelAdmin

```
polymorphic_models = (MyModel1, MyModel2, MyModel3)
for child in polymorphic_models:
    @admin.register(child)
    class PolymorphicChildModelAdmin2(PolymorphicChildModelAdmin):
        if child == MyModel1:
            inlines = [MyMode1lInline]
        base_model = child
        show_in_index = False
```